# How to use core-shared-lib to check if a URL exists?

Tags: polymer, jsonp

Because of the CORS issue, I cannot use `core-ajax`.

It was suggested to use `polymer-jsonp`, which has been deprecated and `core-shared-lib` is the alternative. But `core-shared-lib` seems nothing like `polymer-jsonp`, and the document is not helping a lot.

So how to use this element exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to request JSON data cross-domain and the service supports JSONP you can use [`byutv-jsonp`](http://coderfin.github.io/byutv-jsonp/components/byutv-jsonp/).

> The byutv-jsonp element () exposes network request functionality. It is a Polymer v1.0+ element that facilitates making JSONP requests. It uses Polymer behaviors (Byutv.behaviors.Jsonp). It is patterned after Polymer's iron-ajax element (). It has been tested using unit tests. It is part of the BYUtv Elements group of elements.